# Changing color of Paint in android,using SharedPreferences

Tags: android

I have two different activities. One's view contains `RadioButton`s that give the user choice to select color, then when the user draws on the `Canvas`,the color selected in the options activity is used to draw.
Here's the code for the Options `Activity`:

```
            RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
            int checkedRadioButton = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            String radioButtonSelected = "";
            switch (checkedRadioButton) {
              case R.id.CheckRed : radioButtonSelected = "Red";
                                              break;
              case R.id.CheckBlue : radioButtonSelected = "Blue";
                                          break;
              case R.id.CheckWhite : radioButtonSelected = "White";
                                          break;
            }
            SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
            Editor prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();
            prefsEditor.putString("setColor", radioButtonSelected);
            prefsEditor.commit();
```

Here's the xml for this `Activity`:

```
    <RadioGroup 
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="vertical" >


    <RadioButton 
        android:id="@+id/CheckWhite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="White" />

    <RadioButton 
        android:id="@+id/CheckRed" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Red" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/CheckBlue" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Blue" />

</RadioGroup>
```

Notice that `CheckWhite` has `android:checked="true"`. I want that to be true for whichever color the user selects later on.

Here's the code for the `Activity` that does the drawing:

```
        SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
        drawColor = appSharedPrefs.getString("setColor", "White");
        if(drawColor.equals("White"))
            intColor = 1;
        if(drawColor.equals("Red"))
            intColor = 2;
        if(drawColor.equals("Blue"))
            intColor = 3;


        mPaint = new Paint();
        if(intColor == 1)
            mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        if(intColor == 2)
            mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        if(intColor == 3)
            mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Unfortunately,the color doesn't change. Kindly help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `OnCheckedChangedListener` to your `RadioGroup` and in the method `onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)` put the code that sets the preferences for the user color. Some code:

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                String radioButtonSelected = "";
                switch (checkedId) {
                  case R.id.CheckRed : radioButtonSelected = "Red";
                                                  break;
                  case R.id.CheckBlue : radioButtonSelected = "Blue";
                                              break;
                  case R.id.CheckWhite : radioButtonSelected = "White";
                                              break;
                }
                SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
                Editor prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();
                prefsEditor.putString("setColor", radioButtonSelected);
                prefsEditor.commit();

            }
        });
```

**EDIT:**
Remove the `android:checked="true"` from the xml layout (from the white `RadioButon`) and then in your Options screen set the checked `RadioButton` according to your preferences:

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
radioGroup.clearCheck();
SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
drawColor = appSharedPrefs.getString("setColor", "White");
if(drawColor.equals("White"))
    radioGroup.check(R.id.CheckWhite);
if(drawColor.equals("Red"))
    radioGroup.check(R.id.CheckRed);
if(drawColor.equals("Blue"))
    radioGroup.check(R.id.CheckBlue);
```

Comment: Thanks. A little more of help? Now the color changing works. But every time I open the Options screen, the RadioButton for white is selected,even though the current color maybe something else. So how do I change that?